# Switching several relays at the same time parallel with one or several transistors?

Tags: transistors, relay, parallel

I need to switch 2 or maybe 3 or 4 relais at the same time.

Is it best to have for each relay a separate transistor? Or is it perfectly fine to use just one transistor and one diode for several relays.

In this case I plan to use these relays: Fujitsu A-5W-K
https://www.fujitsu.com/downloads/MICRO/fcai/relays/a.pdf

[image: Relay circuit with transistor and diode]

Edit: I know that I need 5V for a 5V relay. The circuit is just a stock photo from the internet.

And I know that I could buy other relays which have more contacts. I plan to use these relays because I can get them for a good price from my local supplier.

Comment: you can buy a multi-relay module

Answer (score 1):

First, the A-5W-K relay is wrong for 12V supply, its nominal coil voltage is only 5V.

Now, assuming you use A-12W-K model, the ON current is 12mA. This is low enough so you can connect several of them in parallel, providing your switching element and flyback diode are rated accordingly.

Whether or not it is "best" is debatable. If it was up to me I'd use simple relay driver for each relay. Something like [NUD3124](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/NUD3124-D.PDF) removes the need in resistor and diode, simplifying the circuit a lot. Also, if you use dual package you'd only need one extra component per two relays.

Comment: Thanks. You write "If it was up to me I'd use simple relay driver for each relay." Now the question is obviously why would you do that for each relay and not for two or three together?

Comment: If nothing else it'll give me a flexibility to control relays independently if I wanted to later. Then it would provide reliability, as one burnt out  switch will disable one relay only, instead of all of them. Finally, with one component being able to switch two relays I simply don't see a reason to fiddle with parallel connections and worry about currents, flyback diodes etc. Choosing properly rated relay driver is so much easier.